# Converting decimal number to flag values

Tags: lua, libtorrent

I have some constraints like so:

```
interesting = 0x1
choked = 0x2
remote_interested = 0x4
remote_choked = 0x8
supports_extensions = 0x10
local_connection = 0x20
handshake = 0x40
connecting = 0x80
queued = 0x100
on_parole = 0x200
seed = 0x400
optimistic_unchoke = 0x800
rc4_encrypted = 0x100000
plaintext_encrypted = 0x200000
```

and the documentation tells me *'The flags attribute tells you in which state the peer is in. It is set to any combination of the enums above'* so basically I call the dll and it fills in the structure with a decimal number representing the flag values, a few examples:

```
2086227
170
2098227
106
```

How do I from the decimal determine the flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to determine which flags were set, you need to use the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation ([`bit32.band()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-bit32.band) in Lua 5.2).  For example:

```
function hasFlags(int, ...)
    local all = bit32.bor(...)
    return bit32.band(int, all) == all
end

if hasFlags(2086227, interesting, local_connection) then
    -- do something that has interesting and local_connection
end
```

Comment: In Lua 5.1 or LuaJIT, bit32 is not available but you can use luabitop instead. It comes natively with LuaJIT, you need to install it for 5.1.

Comment: There exists back port of `bit32` to Lua 5.1 (https://raw.github.com/hishamhm/lua-compat-5.2/bitlib-5.2.2/lbitlib.c). It exists in LuaRocks and LuaDist. And LuaJIT has its own bit library